# Git, inverted rebase

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

In git, I accidentally rebased master branch on feature branch. Now I must undo that, but the problem is master doesn't have origin to reset to yet.

How do I undo the rebase of master on feature? And more interestingly, is it possible to actually perform *inverted* rebase, e.g removing part of history from the branch based on other branch?

Comment: Are you on your local master? It won't a problem if you don't publish your changes to shared remote.

Comment: As long as you haven't publish it yet,  `git reset --hard` can always be used.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably more an undo than an *inverted* rebase.

Use `git reflog master` to find out the sha1 of the commit of master before the rebase and do a `git reset --hard`.

2 advices before doing that:

- stash your uncommited changes if you have some before doing it or they could be lost
- read some doc on the 2 commands to understand what you will do (to be able to get you out of the sheet if you miss something)